# How to run initialize when switching view in Gluon mobile

Tags: java, gluon-mobile

I am using gluon mobile to build my app and I want to update the `home` window when switching to it with the `view.getAppManager.goHome()` but unlike setting a new scene in javafx this does not run the `initialize` function in my home controller.

At first I tried fixing it by changing the scene like in javafx but because the of the way that gluon mobile works it discards a lot of the benefits of the API, like the App bar and so on. I was hoping that there is an easy way to run initialize when switching a view. Another fix I tried is to make my update method public and run it through my other view controller but because I cannot make it satatic, I got nullPointerExeptions when making a `new HomePresenter.myUpdateToHomeView`.  Does Someone know how to work around this?

Comment: Because View nodes are cached once created, `initialize()` is called once. However you could make use of `View::setOnShowing` (see [javadoc](https://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/6.2.2/com.gluonhq.charm.glisten/com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/mvc/View.html#onShowingProperty)), which will get called every time the view is shown on top (i.e. after switching to it from other view).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.